# How can I access postcss variables in styled components for media-query?

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, styled-components

I'm using a CDN, which has a bunch of defined pcss variables that I would like to use in my styled components. I was able to use the color vars easily via `var(--color-green)`. However, the media-queries variables don't seem to work. Anyone know why this might the case?

This is what I've tried, where `--media-query-max-small` is defined in the cdn as `max-width: 647px`

```
const comp = styled.div`
  @media (var(--media-query-max-small)) { }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

As a creator of PostCSS, I recommend to use [astroturf](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/astroturf). It is CSS-in-JS solution with styled-components API, but in contrast to styled-component, astroturf doesn’t have runtime (SC has 15 KB runtime), parse CSS only during build (SC parse it every time on the client) and support PostCSS and many other CSS tools.

In your case, just put `postcss-loader` for CSS and `astroturf/loader` for JS files. Everything will work.